# csync2 won't install

Tags: apt

I've tried to install csync2 using apt-get, but I am getting the error below.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve this or failing that, could you tell me if this problem could be because the dependencies haven't been ported to ARM?

I've tried this now with debian and occidentalis

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 csync2 : Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.17-0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: have you tried "apt-get update" before you try and install csync2?

Comment: yeah I tried, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: try: sudo apt-get install --yes csync2

Comment: That gave the same error

Comment: Have you tried to install the dependencies separately (to see if any errors occur)? `apt-get install libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26`

Comment: Yeah I tried before, it gave no error. Just double checked, and it just says they are on the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here the results of a short investigation:

As you already know csync2 does not want to be installed using apt-get, the reason for this (as far as I can see) is that the debian people made a mistake in the dependencies of the libgnutls26 package. It states on a package line that it will break csync2 versions lower or equal then 1.34-2.2, which is odd because the version provided IS version 1.34-2.2, I guess the error is that the 'break' rule of the package should state versions LOWER then 1.34-2.2 and not LOWER OR EQUAL then version 1.34-2.2

What does it help to know this: NOTHING.

But there is a way to get csync2 installed anyway, here is how:

first we're only going in download the package using:

```
sudo apt-get download csync2
```

After running this command the package (csync2_1.34-2.2_armhf.deb) should be as a file in the directory you started the command in.

After that I needed to install using the normal way two additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install librsync1
sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

And for a final working version you'll also need one of these installed:

```
openbsd-inetd OR inet-superserver
```

Now for the csync2 part, we're going to use this command to install it:

```
sudo dpkg --install csync2_1.34-2.2_armhf.deb
```

It will complain about the same stuff as apt-get did before, but it will install it anyway. One latest check to see if all library requirements are met:

```
ldd /usr/sbin/csync2
```

should output something like:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0x40249000)
libgnutls-openssl.so.27 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-openssl.so.27 (0x400a3000)
libsqlite.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite.so.0 (0x400b4000)
librsync.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librsync.so.1 (0x40081000)
libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls.so.26 (0x4010b000)
libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtasn1.so.3 (0x4027e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x40294000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x401c6000)
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x40009000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x401dd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x401fc000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x403c3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x40038000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x40056000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x40072000)
```

In the output shown above there should be no, 'File not Found' Errors, if there are you need to install those libs using the normal apt-get way.

Now you have a (as far as I can see) working version on csync2 on your RPi. starting csync2 does result in a help screen and not some coredump, error or otherwise not working thing, so I guess it is now a matter of configuring it and done...